# Is there a function with such properties?

Tags: functions, continuity

Is there a monotonically increasing (decreasing), noncontinuous function with the domain $\mathbb{R}$? Or for every function, if it is monotonically increasing (decreasing), and the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, then is the function continuous on the domain (in this case $\mathbb{R}$)? The last claim seems true for me, I tried to prove it, but I have no success in it. I tried to prove this by contradiction. But I'm not asking for proof, I'm just asking: Does this seem true to you or can you find a counterexample?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ for $x\leq 0$, $f(x)=x+1$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @Wojowu But domain is $R$

Comment: That function is defined on all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Wojowu I know, but you said "for x>0"

Comment: The function is defined differently for $x\leq 0$ and for $x>0$, but altogether it's still a single function with domain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Wojowu Oh, yes. I misunderstood you, at first. Thanks, a lot, for a counterexample.

Comment: There is a result (see if you can prove it): if $f$ is nondecreasing, then it is continuous except at countably many points.  (This is of course a stronger result than Arian's continuous almost everywhere.)

Comment: @GEdgar Does it work for nonincreasing too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a celebrated result in mathematics due to Lebesgue and it is often referred to as  the Differentiation Theorem. It states:

If $f$ is monotone on some open interval $I$ then $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere on the interval $I$ (this includes also the situation when $I=\mathbb{R}$).

Almost everywhere means that a property holds for all values in the interval except for a set of values in the interval of measure zero. Consequently almost everywhere differentiability implies at least almost everywhere continuous (however not necessarily continuous everywhere). As an archetype  example you can take the step function $f(x):=[x]$ where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. This function is monotone increasing but not continuous everywhere.

Comment: By increasing(decreasing) I meant strictly increasing(decreasing), so your example doesn't work properly, but still thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош ok but in that case you can still construct examples of strictly monotone like the one given above in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this counterexample.